# Copy photos from places album to PC

Tags: iphone, photos

In the iPhone photos app, there are now special folders (Places, People, etc.). Unfortunately, photos in these albums will not import automatically into Windows when the iPhone is connected via USB.

Photos in the Places album do not show up in the "All Photos" album or the "Camera Roll".

Does anyone know of a procedure for getting photos from these albums (specifically, the Places album) onto a Windows PC?

Answer (score 2):

An alternate method for download is:

1. Visit https://icloud.com
2. Log in using your Apple ID
3. Select the Photos app
4. Select the photos you wish to download
5. Click the Download icon at the top right of the window

Answer (score 1):

Your camera roll have all the photos no matter which album is it you maybe have to look up closely but all the pictures that you have in your phone no matter what album is it should be in your camera roll besides the one you deleted from any of the album or your camera roll, that should be in the deleted folder.

Comment: Um, no it doesn't. When I copy all of the photos from the DCIM folder (or when I import photos) to Windows, it's missing a bunch. The ones that are missing are all of the ones in the Places folder. Even though those pictures are in the "All photos" folder, they do not get imported or copied.